# Time Machine can't find AFP/SMB shares

Tags: macos, time-machine, nas

I have an Ubuntu NAS setup with both SMB and AFP shares, both of which I can access from my Windows machines and Macbook Air. I have also verified that I can copy files to these shares from my MBA.

But Time Machine on Lion doesn't show any of these shares, only "Set Up Other Time Capsule". What do I need to do for it to show these shares?

I've tried `defaults write com.apple.systempreferences TMShowUnsupportedNetworkVolumes 1` and `defaults read com.apple.systempreferences TMShowUnsupportedNetworkVolumes` returns `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use netatalk 2.2, which is the only version that supports Time Machine backups from Lion.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I just returned my MBA, so won't be able to test this in a while, but will accept your answer for now. If anyone wonders, the version in Ubuntu 11.04's repo is 2.1.4